# UINavigationBar title colour for VCs in a navigation stack doesn't change when back button is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I've a navigation controller which has 3 VCs in it.
Navigation Controller -> VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3
VC1's title is white
VC2's title colour is blue
VC3's title colour is red

When I go back from, let's say, VC3 to VC2 by clicking on VC3's back button, VC2's title colour doesn't change to blue but it remains red.

I read somewhere that we can't have different title colours in same Navigation Controller stack. Is it true?

If not then how to set title's colour in this case?

I'm setting title colour in viewDidAppear as suggest elsewhere but it doesn't work for me in my project. I've created a new project and setup dummy view to test where it works but not in my actual project. I'm not sure what is missing or what I'm doing wrong. Where to look for it?

I've added print and it does print setting correct title colour but it doesn't actually set it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change every navigation title color in viewwillappear()